# How to write/read string data from two different threads in Android/Java

Tags: java, android, string, multithreading

I have an Android application that receives ASCII strings (so every character in the string corresponds to exactly one byte) from a BLE device in thread A.

These strings come in chunks with a maximum length. For example, lets say that the max length is 4, and we receive the following strings:

**"ABCD"** (4), **"EFGH"** (4), **"I\r\n"** (3)

At the other hand, I have another thread B that needs to read these strings but as a complete line. In the example, after receiving all three packets, this thread should read a line:

**"ABCDEFGHI"**

My first bet was to implement a custom InputStream and OutputStream using a common underlying BlockingQueue. Then using an OutputStreamWriter to write incoming strings in thread A and an InputStreamReader wrapped inside a BufferedStream to use the readLine() function from thread B, but it is not working.

I can see that bytes (chunks) are added to the queue when using the custom OutputStream on thread A but when I call readLine() from thread B, it blocks and never returns a string even when I know a full line has been added to the underlying queue.

I'm pretty sure I'm reinventing the wheel here and I've been unable to find a definitive answer searching the Web. There must be a better way to do this in Java/Android. It sounds like a very common pattern.

I mostly do things in C# so there might be some class(es) I'm missing. I took a look at ByteBuffer also but it seems that going this way forces me to implement my own readLine() function because there is no InputStream to be used by BufferedReader, etc.

Comment: Hard to know what's going wrong without seeing code. Are you flushing your output stream so the output isn't stuck in a buffer somewhere? You might also want to look at using [`Pipe`s](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/Pipe.html) instead if I/O streams.

Comment: Yes, I'm flushing my output stream. I can see bytes going into the underlying queue. Anyway, the question is more related to a "good", "best" or "preferred" way of doing what I need rather than my custom implementation. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As recommended by Ted Hopp I finally used a **PipedInputStream** and **PipedOutputStream** (wrapped inside OutputStreamWriter and BufferedReader).

It works like a charm and does exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can easily send data between threads with **[Greenrobot's EventBus](http://greenrobot.org/eventbus/)**.

Greenrobot's EventBus is a library that allows communication between components (Activity, Fragment, Services and backgrounds threads).

build.gradle

```
dependencies {      
    compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'     
}
```

**1. LISTENER (Thread A)**

```
public class BleListener{
    private static Context _context;
    private static BleListener _instance;
    private static ListenerThread _listenerThread;
    private static boolean _isListenerThreadEnable = false;

    private BleListener(Context context){
        _context = context;

        // set ble config and open ble port in here
        // ....

        // enable listener thread
        if (!_isListenerThreadEnable) {
             _listenerThread = new ListenerThread();
             _listenerThread.start();
             _isListenerThreadEnable = true;
        }

    }

    // call this function from outer class
    public static BleListener getInstance(Context context) {
        if (_instance == null) {
            _instance = new BleListener(Context context);
        }
        return _instance;
    }

    private class ListenerThread extends Thread {

        ListenerThread() {
            // setting your receive buffer, thread priority in here
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {

            while (_isListenerThreadEnable) {
                synchronized (_bleDevice) {

                    int _receivedCount = _bleDevice.getQueueStatus();

                    while (_receivedCount > 0) {
                        // append your received data in here with ByteBuffer or StringBuffer
                        // ..

                        // parsing data for get valid data
                        // ..

                        // send valid data out when receive special character (end of message flag) or when timeout received with EventBus
                        EventBus.getDefault().post( ValidModal);                    
                    }
                }
                Thread.Yield();
           }
       }
    }
}
```

**2. MAIN (Thread B - Read data from Thread A)**

Subscribers also need to register themselves to and unregister from the bus. Only while subscribers are registered, they will receive events. In Android, in activities and fragments you should usually register according to their life cycle. For most cases onStart/onStop works fine:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();


    EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);

    super.onStop();
}
```

Subscribers implement event handling methods (also called “subscriber methods”) that will be called when an event is posted. These are defined with the @Subscribe annotation.

```
@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
public void onMessage(ValidModal) {
    // You will get valid data from thread A here.
    //..
}
```

Comment: Definetly something to look at. Thank you.